# Conan: Handling dependent libraries in CI/CD

Tags: c++, artifactory, conan

We have recently broken a monolithic repo up into separate repos one for the application and several others for common code identified to be libraries. Each repo generates a conan package and uploads the library to artifactory. Some of the libs are inter dependent and then our main application in another repo consumes all 10 libraries too.

Herein lies the problem.

If I make changes to `lib-a` which subsequently has consumers `lib-b` & `lib-c`, which then may have there own consumer `lib-d`, have others found means of handling this through their pipeline. I don't necessarily want to update to the latest revision each time, but at least want to be notified that my dependent library has been updated.

I have been looking at finding examples of this but to no avail. I have seen the concept of [lockfiles](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/versioning/lockfiles/ci.html) but dont really understand how they work and if they fit my requirement

Comment: This happens all the time in OSS projects. Look at any library in NPM. Since these are all internal applications, I think your best bet is to setup an announcement board where each lib team can announce new versions ready for use (preferably then with a changelog)

Comment: @fredrik Well libraries are maintained by the one team. I guess its the cumbersome and error prone process of having to manually check for each dependency and update and the possible issue of missing a dependency.

Comment: I didn't suggest checking for updates - but announcing them. If it's all in one team - it should be easy.